# send inline query result error (Telegram)

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

I wanted to make an inline bot! and when i do this:

```
function sendResponse($url, $data){
    $ch = curl_init();
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('inline_query_id' => $data['inline_query_id'], 'results' => json_encode($data['results'])));
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    return $output;
}
```

It wont work, the error (with or without the header): `{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"[Error]: Bad request: Field \"message_text\" must be of type String"}`

but when I do it like this:

```
function sendResponse($url, $data){
    $ch = curl_init();
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url.'?inline_query_id='.rawurlencode($data['inline_query_id']).'&results='.rawurlencode(json_encode($data['results']))); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $q);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    return $output;
}
```

It works ! the problem is the second method request URI will be too large so I cannot use it!

Any way I can send these data is okay with me! thanks!

and the code for making $data is here:

```
$result = connectWebsite(SITE_SEARCH_URL, urlencode($update['inline_query']['query']));
$result = json_decode($result);
$output = array();
$output['inline_query_id'] = $update['inline_query']['id'];
$i = 0;
foreach($result as $post){
    $data = array();
    $data['type'] = 'article';
    $data['id'] = strval($post->ID);
    $data['title'] = '('.$post->atypes.') '.$post->title;
    if(strlen($post->content) > 2100)
        $tmp = substr($post->content, 0, 2096).'...';
    $data['message_text'] = '<b>'.$post->title.'</b>'.ucwords($post->genre, ',').$tmp;
    $data['parse_mode'] = 'HTML';
    if(strlen($post->content) > 200)
        $tmp = substr($post->content, 0, 196).'...';
    //$data['description'] = ucwords($post->genre, ',').'  |  '.$tmp;
    $output['results'][$i] = $data;
    $i++;
    if($i == MAX_RESULTS)
        break;
}   
sendResponse(API_URL.'answerInlineQuery', $output);
```

Comment: oh. and if you are giving a -1 because it's a duplicate or something, please answer it too (or at least a link). professor of -1s!

thanks

Comment: You can debug it just from the message to get from api call `[Error]: Bad request: Field \"message_text\" must be of type String` so make sure that `message_text` is String;

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 it is !

Comment: Maybe you should `var_dump` your `$output`

Comment: @Maak ["message_text"]=> string(160)

Comment: All of them? you do have multiple results, don't you?

Comment: @Maak single or multiple. both... but thanks the problem was solved. the problem was with the substr

Comment: میشه من برای نوشتن این کد کمک کنید ؟ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43754361/how-to-answer-inline-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help someone so I'll answer it myself.

the problem was the UTF-8 encoding

I replaced `substr` with `mb_substr`

besides at the first line I'v added this: `mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8")`

and ... the problem was solved. now I can send my inline query results (or any other command) without the URL length problem

Thanks everyone for your help